# What could be the cause of the little difference between Caffe convolution and Tensorflow output?

Tags: python, tensorflow, caffe

I have Tensorflow network and I ported it in the Caffe format. All weights and algorithm is correct in Caffe and TF, I checked it several times.

But when I run both frameworks and compare their output layer-by-layer, small differences start to appear.

For example, if the result of the `BatchNormalization` at the one point in Caffe is  `0.940091` then for TF at the same point it is `0.939559`, so the difference is `0.0005319999999999769` . Very small but it gets amplified deeper in the network we go, and at the end values are very different.
For `Convolution` difference is present also(`-2.7540846 Caffe` `-2.7540843 TF`) but it gets more noticeable after first `BatchNormalization`

I suppose it might be some internal difference and casting between some sort of `FP16, FP32, FP64`. Have no idea how TF handles conversion from python graph to C++ graph.

May be someone encountered same problem?

Comment: It might be due to "floating point" numbers innacuracy, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate/21896128

Comment: Caffe and Tensorflow have some differences in the implementation of the Batch norm layer. Caffe has divided it into a normalization layer followed by a scaling and bias layer. Another possible issue could be that Caffe expects the input shape with channels first [CxHxW] while Tensorflow wants [HxWxC] by default (see 'data_format' parameter)